# Sorting a list with elements containing dictionary values 

Tags: python, list, sorting, dictionary

I'm trying to make a sorting system with card ranks and their values are obtained from a separate dictionary. In a simple deck of 52 cards, we have 2 to Ace ranks, in this case I want a ranking system where 0 is 10, J is 11, Q is 12, K is 13, A is 14 and 2 is 15 where 2 is the largest valued rank. The thing is, if there is a list where I want to sort rank cards in *ASCENDING* order according to the numbering system, how do I do so?

For example, here is a list, `[3,5,9,7,J,K,2,0]`, I want to sort the list into `[3,5,7,9,0,J,K,2]`. I also made a dictionary for the numbering system as `{'A': 14, 'K': 13, 'J': 11, 'Q': 12, '0': 10, '2': 15}`.

THANKS

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This answer works:

```
    sorted(list_for_sorting, key=dictionary_you_wrote.__getitem__)
```

This does too:

```
    sorted_list = sorted(unsorted_list, key = lambda k: your_dictionary[k])
```

The sorted function uses each entry in the first argument (the object you want to sort), to call the second argument. That way the lamda function returns the value for the given item from the dictionary and sorted can use it as the key.

If any list entry is not in your_dictionary.keys(), this will not work. Either complete the dictionary or use

```
    sorted(unsorted_list, key = lambda k: your_dictionary[k] if k in your_dictionary.keys() else k)
```

Comment: It's usually neater to write `key=dictionary_you_wrote.get`

Comment: Wait so... for the "your_dictionary" section, thats the dictionary to get the number value right? Thanks so much!

Comment: Sorry but this doesn't work as there is a KeyError since the number '3' isn't a key in the dictionary. How do we exclude the elements in the unsorted list if they aren't in the dictionary?

Comment: It is better to complete the dictionary than to exclude elements from the lamda function.

Answer (score 0):

have you already tried

> `sorted(list_for_sorting, key=dictionary_you_wrote.__getitem__)`

?